# Regex for exact number / sting match in between

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I want to make a regex where I can find the exact number in between a string.

eg.  finding the number 2 in 3, 5, 25, 22,2, 15

What I have is /*,2,*/.

But with this regex it matches 22,25 or just anything with a 2 in it. I want it where only match where the number 2 itself is between the commas or without the commas standing alone.

*Update
Both the number(needle) i look for and string(haystack) where i seek it can vary.

Eg if the number i seek is always 2

```
      I want to find them in 2,3,44,23,22,1 or 3,4,22,5,2 or 2 and i should be able to find one match for each of the group of numbers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use boundaries (`\b`) so a leading/trailing comma isn't required.

`/\b2\b/`

Comment: But what I'm looking for is in a string with commas like the example so having boundaries doesn't work.

Comment: the comma isn't counted as part of a boundary. Boundaries will match any non word character (word character being `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or the start/end of a string. So a string of `1,2,3`, the pattern `/\b2\b/` would match `2`. A string of `11,22,33` would match nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of new to regex. What you have worked but I tried on a online regex tester and deem it not working. Now, just tried on another and seem to to work. It was quite easy and as I expected it should be.

Comment: That's fine. A boundary is a way of saying that the character before or after is not a word character. This includes the start and end of the string. http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead:

`,(\d),`   #for any single digit

`,(2),`   #for 2 in particular

Demo:  http://regex101.com/r/vP6jI1

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't make my question clear. The example above is just a example and the number i look for in the string both can vary.                                                                 So if I'm looking for the 2 in 2,45,22,66,2. I wont find a single match.

Comment: @user1467723, In that case, use my first regex as shown in the demo

Comment: @user1467723, Alternatively, you can use : `(^|,)(\d)($|,)` for checking a  single digit between commas or at the start or end of the string. Then you can extract the second captured group using `\2`